# Find a Control inside ASP:Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to access a control inside a Repeater. The control is inside the <ItemTemplate> tag. I am using FindControl but it's always coming out Null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about posting a sample of your Repeater so we can see what's going on?

Comment: The Stackoverflow editor truncates the code when I paste it in.

Comment: Just paste it in, we'll fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that FindControl can only be used in record-level events such as ItemDataBound:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    (ControlTypeCast) e.Item.FindControl("myControl")).SomeProperty = "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're trying to find a control at the wrong point in the page lifecycle. The ItemDataBound event is where you need to look for it.

This example is in vb.net, but I'm sure you get the idea.

```
Protected Sub rp_items_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rp_items.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim someLiteral As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("someliteral")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, spelling the control name wrong :) It may also be that you are searching for a control that exists within another container. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

For vb.net

```
CType(e.Item.FindControl("myControl"), Literal).Text = "foo"
```

For c#

```
[Literal]e.item.FindControl["myControl"].Text="foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         for (int i = 0; i <= repeater1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             Button delete = (Button)repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("btnDelete");
             delete.Visible = true;
             Button edit = (Button)repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("btnEdit");
             edit.Visible = true;
         }
```

Vb.net

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To Repeater1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim CmbTyp As DropDownList = DirectCast(Repeater1.Items(i).FindControl("DropDownList1"),DropDownList)
        Dim SeatN As Label = DirectCast(Repeater1.Items(i).FindControl("label1"), Label)

        styp = CmbTyp.SelectedItem.Text.Trim
        sNo = SeatN.Text



    Next
```