# How access hyperlink control in a repeater i c# .net

Tags: asp.net

There is repeater in my program includin a hyper link.i cant a cess my hyper link control.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink15" runat="server" NavigateUrl="abc.aspx">
```

set enabled=false

so i use

```
HyperLink a = (HyperLink)Repeater1.FindControl("HyperLink15");
```

The hyper link is only enabled for user a and b... so i use the code:

```
if (a && b)
{
    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)Repeater1.FindControl("HyperLink15");
    link.Enabled=true;
    link.Navigateurl="efg.aspx"; 
}
```

But I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Comment: you probably would have got suggestions while trying compose your question. There are numerous questions like yours if you would have searched for the link. I don't know if this might be of complete help, but here is a link to one similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911240/find-a-control-inside-asprepeater . If you scroll this page a bit down, you can find a section called related questions. Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HyperLink a = (HyperLink)Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("HyperLink15");
```

Use above, and Items will contain index.

Or

```
for (int count = 0; count < Repeater1.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            HyperLink a = (HyperLink)Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("HyperLink15");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Repeater onItemDataBound Event` first check below condition.

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
 // find controls here
}
```